# Make hover effect on element last only limited time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my pen: http://codepen.io/explicit_concept/pen/BLgoVG there is script which triggers scale/background color change of .icon elements only on first hover of whole .device div.How to make effect which is triggered on hover to last only 3 seconds for example ?

i have seen it was done by doTimeout jQuery plugin but for learning i would like to make it from scratch.

Should it be done with setTimeout when hover whiche adds class to element and and then when timer is done to undo .addClass ?

this is the jQuery code for hover:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.device').one('mouseenter',function() {
  $(this).find('.icon').addClass('icon-hovered');
    });
$('.device').mouseleave(function() {
  $('.icon').removeClass('icon-hovered');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(() => {
    $(this).find(".icon").removeClass("icon-hovered")
}, 3000); // time in milliseconds
```

In your `mouseenter` listener will work.

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wxmc3qks/1/

On the `mouseleave` event just use the javascript function `setTimeout`. the jQuery `delay` function is for animation delays only and no functions.

```
$(function() {
  $('.button').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
  });

  $('.button').on('mouseleave', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $this.removeClass('hovered');
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that is true, did not manage to handle it with delay.